# Where's the locked chest with a Ranger's gun in chapter 5?

Tags: metro-last-light

After a brief reunion with Pavel in chapter 5, you can hear two guards talking about one of them having a locked chest with a heavily-modified weapon that once belonged to a Ranger. Where can I find that chest, and do I need to do something special to be able to open it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After the 2 guards finish talking, follow the one that leaves the big room and goes towards some lockers, take him out after he unlocks his locker and the gun will be there